# Strange error (Input string is not in correct format.)

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, types, compiler-errors

This is my code:

```
namespace Class_Properties {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        private string firstHeight1 = "";
        public int firstHeight {
            get {
                        return Convert.ToInt32( firstHeight1 );
            }
        }

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
            firstHeight1 = textBox2.Text;

            Form2 secondForm = new Form2();
            secondForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

and then the other class:

```
namespace Class_Properties {
    public partial class Form2 : Form {
        public Form2() {
            InitializeComponent();
            Form1 mainWindow = new Form1();
            this.Height = mainWindow.firstHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run, I type `200` as value for `textbox2` and click `button1`, then Visual Studio says the following exception:

[image]

What could I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the failure:

```
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1 mainWindow = new Form1();
        this.Height = mainWindow.firstHeight;  //<--
```

No matter what you did on the other `Form1`, it won't show up in this one because it's a new instance so `firstHeight == string.Empty` and will fail the parse.

You'll have to send the existing Form1 to Form2:

```
public Form2(Form1 parent)
{
    this.Height = parent.firstHeight;
}

// called like so from Form1:
var form2 = new Form2(this);
```

Though admittedly, it would be better to send only what you need:

```
public Form2(int desiredHeight)
{
    this.Height = desiredHeight;
}

// called like so from Form1:
var form2 = new Form2(this.firstHeight);
```

Comment: this worked... so I have to understand that I can make this work just by passing `Form1` as parameter to `Form2()`...

Comment: @Victor:  I'd really recommend only sending what you need to Form2 instead of Form1 itself.  Coupling is a habit to avoid if you can and based on your example, there's really no need for Form2 to know about Form1.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of firstHeight1 when it throws the exception?

You may want to look at int.TryParse() instead:

```
int output = 0;
int.TryParse(firstHeight1, out output);
return output;
```

If it can't parse the value, it won't set `output`, instead of raising an exception.

More info on int.TryParse: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

EDIT: The problem is you're re-instantiating Form1 and the value is never set in the new instance of Form1, from Form2.  You should set a property in Form2 to that value.

```
class Form2
{
    public int FirstHeight { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.FirstHeight = this.FirstHeight;
form2.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `firstHeight1` is `String.Empty` and no equivalent for empty string can be found in  `Int` type. Hence the error..

In your Form2 instance, the value is still `String.Empty`. First set it to some value.

Answer (score 0):

In `Form2` when you say:

```
Form1 mainWindow = new Form1();
this.Height = mainWindow.firstHeight;
```

You aren't accessing the `Form1` you had been using earlier, you're creating a brand new one with an empty textbox value.

What you should be doing is passing the height value into the second form when it is created:

```
public Form2(int height) 
{
   // use height here
}
```

and in button click:

```
Form2 secondForm = new Form2(firstHeight);
secondForm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
public int? FirstHeight
{
    get
    {
        int? returnValue = null;

        int temp;
        if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out temp))
        {
            returnValue = temp;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Then you just call the `FirstHeight` property when you need the value:

```
if (FirstHeight.HasValue)
{
    // Access the int value like so:
    int height = FirstHeight.Value;
}
```

If you don't want to use a Nullable type, you could do this instead:

```
public int FirstHeight
{
    get
    {
        int returnValue; // Or some other default value you can check against.

        if (!int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out returnValue))
        {
            // If the call goes in here, the text from the input is not convertable to an int.
            // returnValue should be set to 0 when int.TryParse fails.
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like

```
public int FirstHeight
 {
   get
     {
      double Num;
      bool isNum = double.TryParse(firstheight1, out Num);
      if (isNum)
     {
       return firstheight1;
      }
    else
    {
     return 0; or 
     your message goes here 
    }
```

}
      }